# Using comments for feedback instead of deleting questions

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Yesterday I posted a [question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13585/169-and-219-monitor-pair) asking for recommendations about a pair of monitors. I personally thought I had given enough detail on the requirements of this question but a moderator disagreed and therefore closed and deleted the question. I agree there is definitely a requirement for moderator intervention such as when users post questions asking for tech support when in the [help](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help) page it explicitly states this site is not for technical support.

However my question was closed and deleted as the requirements are too broad and subsequently I do not know why the requirements are too broad. Would a comment on the question asking for clarification, especially as I am a new contributor, not have been better to both keep the question open and to improve my future questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's policy on Hardware Recommendations to close and delete questions that don't meet the standards we need questions to meet; doing so helps to avoid giving the impression to others coming later that the question was the kind of thing we're looking for. Deleted questions can still be edited into shape, and once the reason they were closed has been addressed, can be flagged for moderator attention to ask for them to be undeleted and reopened.

Your question was closed because the specifications it gave were too broad to narrow it down to any particular products. With a budget of £1000 and effectively the only requirements being "1x 16:9 and 1x 21:9", there are any number of combinations of products that would meet the requirements you've laid out; without being able to narrow the selection down further, we can't provide definitive recommendations.